# How to get rowcount for all tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I get a rowcount for all tables in MySQL. I can do this databases by database if that is easier.

The purpose is to do a cursory check on my database replication that was just setup.

Answer (score 1):

try [mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html) instead. docs might be scary but together with mk-checksum-filter it's very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are want to check on your replication setup, have you considered using:

- [SHOW SLAVE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-slave-status.html) check the **Seconds_Behind_Master** value
- [SHOW MASTER STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-master-status.html) not as useful as the above

Answer (score 1):

./mysql -utest -ptest dbname -e 'show table status\G' | awk '/Name/ {name = $2}; /Rows/ {print $2"\t"name}' | sort -gr

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://www.a2zmenu.com/MySql/Row-count-of-all-tables-in-a-database%20.aspx) to be a very crisp and clean way to retrieve all the tables along with their row counts.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it went into more detail about the solution in the linked article. Links often go away; if this one does, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

Also useful could be:

```
show table status;
```

Must be executed for each database. Just sho it for you current used database.
Alternate but not fast way:
Use the information schema:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ENGINE, TABLE_ROWS from information_schema.tables;
```

-> ENGINE could be important, maybe you want the filter the information about performance_schema or information_schema, etc. which will not be replicated.